# type error null is not an object (evaluating 'ShareDialog.canShow') in React Native FBSDK

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I have followed this GitHub URL to integrate Facebook sharing in my application.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk
Here is my code:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            shareLinkContent : {
                contentType: 'link',
                contentDescription: 'Facebook sharing is easy!',
                contentUrl: 'https://cabbazar.com',
            },
    }
shareLinkWithShareDialog() {
    var tmp = this;
    ShareDialog.canShow(tmp.state.shareLinkContent).then(
      function(canShow) {
        if (canShow) {
          return ShareDialog.show(tmp.state.shareLinkContent);
        }
      }
    ).then(
      function(result) {
        console.log('handle result: ' + result);
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log('Share fail with error: ' + error);
      }
    );
  }
```

But I am always getting an error in my simulator. Do I need to setup anything in for Xcode? 
I checked this url but it is not solving my problem. 
[null is not an object (evaluating 'ShareDialog.canShow')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54696944/null-is-not-an-object-evaluating-sharedialog-canshow)

[image: This is the error which I am facing.]
Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes auto link doesn't work. So you have to link manually using `react-native link react-native-fbsdk`